# LG X Screen fastboot

Tags: android, adb, root, lg

I have a LG X Screen android 6.0.1 and I've been trying to boot into fastboot but I can't. I've already tried both keys combinations and abd commands and doesn't work. can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast boot Mode LG X screen K500N. In the first step the Power key for a short while to switch off your device. Then prepare a *Micro USB cable* connected to PC or laptop. In the next step start holding the Volume Down key for a few seconds.

**Important part** is u need to connect it t PC for the fast boot mode to work